# SQL Query for information *not* in database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a **large list** of email addresses, and I need to determine which of them are *not* already in my database. Can I construct a query that will tell me this information?

I am using **SQL Server 2000**, if it requires non-standard extensions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

make a temporary table, load the e-mailaddresses into the temporary table and then do a NOT IN query such as

```
SELECT emailaddress FROM temp_table WHERE emailaddress NOT IN (SELECT emailaddress FROM table)
```

you could extend that with an INSERT INTO

Answer (score 5):

For a huge list, I would recommend loading that list into a second table (e.g., `TEMP_EMAIL_ADDRESS`), then use:

```
SELECT
  EMAIL
FROM
  TEMP_EMAIL_ADDRESS
WHERE
  EMAIL NOT IN (SELECT EMAIL FROM EMAIL_ADDRESS)
```

**Data Transformation**

If your data is in a text file named **emails.txt** (one row per line), you can create the insert statements using the following DOS command:

```
FOR /F %i IN (emails.txt) DO echo INSERT INTO TEMP_EMAIL_ADDRESS (EMAIL) VALUES ('%i') >> insert-email.sql
```

That command will create a new file called **insert-email.sql** in the current directory, containing all the inserts you need to inject the existing list of e-mail addresses into the database.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you import the email addresses as a table and just check that way against whatever table you already have?

Other than that, you could pass in the list of email addresses as an XML datatype or a table datatype and query against that.

Answer (score 1):

Create a table "newaddresses" that has all of your query email addresses.

Do something like this:

(off the top of my head, syntax may not be 100% correct; hopefully gives you the right idea)

```
select n.email
from newaddresses n
left join alreadysubscribed a
    on n.email = a.email
where a.email is null
```

This joins the two tables on the email addresses, and then gives you a list of only the entries where the join failed.

Comment: I'd vote for this one, since it does it without a sub-query, and so will be much more efficient

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could create an index on emails:

```
CREATE INDEX email_index ON my_table(email)
```

and then simply check with

```
SELECT email FROM my_table WHERE my_table.email = some_email
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... Nobody mentioned IF EXISTS. That would have been my first thought:

`IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM MyTable where MyTable.email = "someemail@somewhere.com`

Although, perhaps the performance is no different from NOT IN.

Hope this helps.